# Any approach to ignore Error of source package in Python?

Tags: python, exception

So here is the situation.

```
import foo_package
def my_func():
    foo_package.foo_func()
```

I know that `foo_func` will throw an exception because it tries to remove a file that does not exist by `os.remove(path)`. I am wondering if there is any way **FROM THE OUTSIDE** that I can force `foo_package.foo_func()` to ignore that exception and continue running.

Usually we would try to catch the exception

```
import foo_package
def my_func():
    try:
        foo_package.foo_func()
    except:
        # deal with exception
        pass
```

But here are the limits:

1. I know the exception does not affect anything else, and I want it to continue running from the next line, instead of catching it from the outside
2. I cannot change the `foo_package` since it is a third-party library.

Comment: Simplest fix would be to create the file (empty, just an `open` with `w`, then close it) before you do the import.

Comment: Create the file yourself, so the `remove()` doesn't fail.  Or monkeypatch `os.remove()` to be a dummy function that does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by `monkeypatch`? Could you elaborate on it a bit? Thanks. @JohnGordon

Comment: @cdarke I tried, but then I find that the file was generated with a random name in that package... The reason that `os.remove(file_path)` files is that it tries to call `os.remove(file_path)` twice...

Comment: Monkey patching is basically masking the standard library function with one of your own.  It can be done easily in python by reassigning the name.  There are dangers, you can inadvertently trap legitimate calls, not to mention causing support confusion.  Tread carefully, monkey-patching can be a minefield.

Comment: So, the package randomly generates a filename then tried to delete it?  That sounds like a bug to me.  Why not go back to the third-party who supplied the module and complain?

Comment: @cdarke Submitted the issue already. It might take a while for them to fix it. Meanwhile, I need to get my system up running as soon as possible...